# From date and time in column tot date in column and time in rows to be able to make a 2D chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a lot of data in Excel in the following format:

```
 column1    column2    column3 
 date       hour       variable
```

I want to make a two dimensional chart: `time` on the X-axis / `date` on the Y-axis, and colour the chart lines to correspond with the `variable` values.

I need to do this with data from several years so can anyone suggest how to automate this please?

Comment: You could add extra columns - one per color. Use the Excel function  IF to fill the extra column cells with either blank or a number depending on whether a given data value should have the color assigned to the column.

Answer (score 0):

@Axel Kemper seems to have a viable solution, provided *blank* is replaced with say *#N/A* (to avoid discontinuities in the lines). However, this may be a case for a 3D chart because using an XY (Scatter) chart with Straight Lines and Markers does not appear to very likely to be a great aid to visualisation:

[image: SU576330 example]